# Payment transaction failed in Magento due to invalid XML request

Tags: xml, magento, request, payment

I am getting this error when a user tries to place an order on my site. It happens once in a while.

Payment transaction failed.
Reason
You submitted an invalid XML request. Please verify your request and retry the transaction.
Checkout Type
onepage

```
> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'You submitted an invalid
> XML request. Please verify your request and retry the transaction.' in
> /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/Mage.php:594 Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Optimalpayments/Model/PaymentMethod.php(161):
> Mage::throwException('You submitted a...')
> #1 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(408):
> Mage_Optimalpayments_Model_PaymentMethod->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment),
> '175.14')
> #2 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(385):
> Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
> #3 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(569):
> Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice->capture()
> #4 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(375):
> Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->_invoice()
> #5 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(317):
> Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(NULL)
> #6 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(877):
> Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->place()
> #7 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1095):
> Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_placePayment()
> #8 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Order->place()
> #9 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105):
> call_user_func(Array)
> #10 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159):
> Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
> #11 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189):
> Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
> #12 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249):
> Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
> #13 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(774):
> Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
> #14 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(511):
> Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
> #15 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419):
> Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
> #16 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
> #17 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
> #18 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
> #19 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
> #20 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ca/httpdocs/index.php(71): Mage::run('', 'store')
> #21 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the 3rd party payment processing module you have for optimal payments (`Mage_Optimalpayments`) is sending XML to the Optimal Payments server that the Optimal Payments server doesn't like.  Take a look at the code around line `161` in

```
app/code/local/Mage/Optimalpayments/Model/PaymentMethod.php
```

This will tell you why the Magento module thinks it's received invalid XML.  You may be able to debug further from there.  I'd contact the module developer for support.